# How to stop audio of Music App while playing audio from my app?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am facing one issue is :-

If audio of *Music Application* is playing and I will open my app that time both the audio are playing parallel.

I want to stop music of Music App and want to continue my app audio.

That is happening in if I will go to inactive state (play music from music app) to active state of app.

I am initialising the AVAudioPlayer :-

```
func setAudioSession(){
    // Set Audio session

    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
    catch {
        print("AVAudioSession error")
    }
} 


func startPlayer(at index: Int) {
    do {
        self.playingItem = self.queueArray[index]
        self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
        self.player?.currentTime = beginTime
        self.player?.delegate = self
        self.player?.prepareToPlay()
        self.player?.play()
    }
    catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

How I can stop music of Music App and want to continue my app audio
?

Comment: remove `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers`, only set category `setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)`

Comment: OK I will try this.
Thanks

Comment: try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

Comment: and its working or not?

Comment: I think it should work.
Let me check. Thanks